# Show Row Details as a Popup/ToopTip form on Mouse Hover for each row in KendoUI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a grid populated with data and 
i want to show only 3 or 2 columns and hide rest of columns cause the grid goes very wide.
when the mouse is hovered over a row i want to show all the columns of that row as as popup /tooltip form.

Please help me with this. I searched a lot and only found out Editable popup and with button click not with hover.

```
function PopulateGrid() {
    $("#recentNews").kendoGrid({

        columns: [
            { field:      'Date', title: 'Date', width: 80,
                template: '#=kendo.toString(toDate(NewsDate), "yyyy/MMM/dd") #'
            },
            { field:      'TradeTime', title: 'Time', width: 60,
                template: '#=kendo.toString(toDate(NewsTime), "hh:mm:ss") #'
            },

            { field: 'Title', title: 'Description', width: 200 },
            { field: 'Country', title: 'Country', width: 40 },
            { field: 'Economy', title: 'Economoy', width: 40 }

        ],

        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url:      'Home/GetNews',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type:     "POST"
                }
            },
            schema:    {
                data:  function (data) {
                    return data.data;
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data.total;
                }
            },
            pageSize:  100

        },
        //            change: onChange,
        //          dataBound: onDataBound,
        dataBound:  HoverOnGrid,
        pageable:   true,
        sortable:   true,
        scrollable: true,
        height:     565,
        width:      2000
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using KendoUI `grid` [`detailTemplate`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#detailtemplate-function) instead of `hoover`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate *questions* about what you are trying to implement:

1. Bind hover to the `Grid` rows (easy).
2. Generate a popup / tooltip that shows the rest of the columns (easy but requires some amount of coding).

Since it seems that you have already defined a function called `HoverOnGrid` lets write it as:

```
function HoverOnGrid() {
    $("tr", "#recentNews").on("mouseover", function (ev) {
        // Invoke display tooltip / edit row
        var rowData = grid.dataItem(this);
        if (rowData) {
            showTooltip(rowData);
        }
    });
}
```

where `grid` is:

```
var grid = $("#recentNews").kendoGrid({
    ...
}).data("kendoGrid";
```

Now, the tricky question, how to show a tooltip / popup... There is no predefined way of doing it, you should do it by yourself. The closes that you can get is defining `HoverOnGrid` as:

```
function HoverOnGrid() {
    $("tr", "#recentNews").on("click", function (ev) {
        grid.editRow(this);
    })
}
```

and the `Grid` initialization say:

```
 editable:   "popup",
```

But this opens a `popup` but with fields on edit mode (something that you can hack defining in the `dataSource.schema.model` that all fields are not editable:

```
model: {
    fields: {
        Date:      { editable: false },
        TradeTime: { editable: false },
        Title:     { editable: false },
        Country:   { editable: false },
        Economy:   { editable: false }
    }
}
```

But it still shows `update` and `cancel` buttons in the `popup`.

So, my recommendation is writing a piece of code that creates that `tooltip`.

**EDIT**: For hiding the `tooltip` you should first intercept the `mouseout` event:

```
$("tr", "#recentNews").on("mouseout", function (ev) {
    // Hide Tooltip
    hideTooltip();
});
```

where `hideTooltip` might be something as simple as:

```
var tooltipWin = $("#tooltip_window_id").data("kendoWindow");
tooltipWin.close()
```

assuming that you are always using the same `id` for the `tooltip` (in this example, `tooltip_window_id`).

Comment: Thanks a lot OnaBai it was very useful I created a kendo window in a div and i show it on hover , however i still have some problems a) how to close/hide it on mouseleave b) how to show this popup window near currently hoverd row.. Once again thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: See **EDIT** on how to close the window and instead of using `hover` event, I think it's better using `mouseover` otherwise there are some strange glitches when you move mouse horizontally over the same row and cross cells (at least on my browser).

Comment: Thanks OnaBai it did work. 
To set the position of popup i used e.clientX & e.clientY..and to send the hovered row data in popup I made few templates and passed in the value of this.cell[index].innerText for required cells. 
I used innerText instead of dataItem cause i thought its easier to format the desired details.
Ther are some glitches though ,I would like to fix the position of popup on each row instead of e.cleintY,e.clientX.
and the popup window is a bit shaky sometimes when any row is hovered over the mouse pointer and popup windopw blink a bit fast , specially in firefox ..

Comment: For solving the blinking problem is why I did recommend replacing `hover` by `mouseover` this way the tooltip/popup will actually follow the mouse.